# AngularJs ng-show and custom directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that resizes the width of an element. It's called **flex-column**. This has been working throughout my application.
The way it works, is by looking at the children of the directive and calculating the height of each child. If the height is greater than the viewport, then it increases the width of the directive.

I have run into an issue with `ng-show`. Normally I use `ng-if`, but in this case I need to use `ng-show`.
The problem with this, is that my directive calculates the height of the children (which is 0 because the element is hidden) and doesn't change the width.

When `ng-show` is true, the content is shown, but my directive does not fire again, because if is only shown. So, my question is:

- Can I override the `ng-show` directive to fire my directive code or
- Is there a way to fire my directive when `ng-show` is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have quite a few different options, but here are a couple:

1. You could modify your directive to listen to an event that you broadcast on the scope from whichever controller changes the condition within the `ng-show` expression from false to true, and re-run your measuring code at that point.
2. You could check in the `link` function of your directive whether the `ng-show` attribute is set, and if so, set up a watch on the expression that will re-measure when it changes from `false` to `true`. I prefer this approach if you're only likely to experience the problem with `ng-show`, because it doesn't require changing any other code.

The code for #2 is pretty simple:

```
function postLink (scope, element, attributes, controller) {
  if (attributes.ngShow) {
    scope.$watch(attributes.ngShow, (newVal, oldVal) {
      if (newVal && !oldVal) {
        controller.measure();
      }  
    }
  } else { 
    // note this is in an else to prevent measure firing twice
    // if ngShow is set and it's initially true.
    controller.measure();
  }
}
```